# Adding a prefix to a string which is an int

Tags: c, string, char, int

Is there a function I can use where I can convert something like `int num = 12;` into a string.

Basically I have a loop which stores a string. The prefix of that string has to be the `int num`. Where `num` keeps increasing each time it does one iteration of the loop

I want to add a prefix to the original string of `hello world` so the output looks like `12. hello world`.

```
char *original = "Hello world";
char *dot_space = ". ";
int num = 0;
while (num < 200) {
    char *num_string = ""; // Some how I convert the num to a string?
    char *new_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(original) + strlen(num_string) + strlen(prefix) + 1;
    strcpy(new_string, num_string);
    strcpy(new_string, prefix);
    strcpy(new_string, original);
    printf("%s\n", new_string);

    num++;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `sprintf()`?

Comment: Do you mean your prefix is the converted number or is there an additional prefix? Otherwise `num_string` and `prefix` should be the same

Comment: For adding a string to another, you need `strcat`. Only the first can be copied with `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `sprintf` to make the concatenated string. Of course the trick is to know the length of the number. Well, we can use local array for that and then copy it to the final string.

Something like

```
// reserve 4 characters for each octet in the `int`
char num_string[sizeof num * CHAR_BIT / 2];

// sprintf returns the length of the string!
int num_len = sprintf(num_string, "%d", i);

// size of char is exactly 1
char *new_string = malloc(strlen(original) + strlen(prefix) + num_len + 1);

// then concatenate all with one sprintf
sprintf(new_string, "%s%s%s", num_string, prefix, original);
```

---

Of course if you're lucky enough to use Glibc and say Linux; or perhaps BSD, and are not bothered with writing portable-everywhere, you can use just `asprintf`:

```
// must be before the include
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

char *new_string;
asprintf(&new_string, "%d%s%s", i, prefix, original);
```

This corresponds to the 4 lines above.

---

Notice that your original approach of `strcpy` x3 would have failed as well; `strcpy` always overwrite starting from the first character in the target buffer; the calls should have been `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strcat`.

Comment: And if you're lucky enough to be using C++, this drops out in two flicks of the wrist.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf(buffer, "%d. %s", num++, str);

Comment: I wouldn't call this terribly helpful. The only thing that makes sense here is that the OP wants to know one actually does the conversion, not how to do it in C.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 If the OP asks "is there a function to convert the integer to a string" we can assume that also includes how to use it.